# where is nginx.lock file?

Tags: centos, nginx

I am using centos 7.2,and I installed nginx 1.9.14 form source,

```
wget -c http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.9.14.tar.gz
tar zxf nginx-1.9.14.tar.gz

wget -O nginx-ct.zip -c https://github.com/grahamedgecombe/nginx-ct/archive/v1.2.0.zip
unzip nginx-ct.zip

cd nginx-1.9.14/

./configure --add-module=../nginx-ct-1.2.0 --with-openssl=../openssl --with-http_v2_module --with-http_ssl_module
make
make install
```

**Question 1:**
I need add the path of `nginx.lock` to shell script,but I can't find it in `/var/lock/`,where is it?

**Question 2:**
The shell script is like this,is it ok?

```
#! /bin/bash
#
# nginx - this script starts and stops the nginx daemon
#
# chkconfig:   - 85 15
# description:  Nginx is an HTTP(S) server, HTTP(S) reverse \
#               proxy and IMAP/POP3 proxy server
#
# processname: nginx
# config:      /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
# pidfile:     /var/run/nginx/nginx.pid

# Source function library.
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

# Source networking configuration.
. /etc/sysconfig/network

# Check that networking is up.
[ "$NETWORKING" = "no" ] && exit 0

nginx="/usr/sbin/nginx"
prog=$(basename $nginx)

NGINX_CONF_FILE="/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf"

[ -f /etc/sysconfig/nginx ] && . /etc/sysconfig/nginx

lockfile=/var/lock/nginx.lock

start() {
    [ -x $nginx ] || exit 5
    [ -f $NGINX_CONF_FILE ] || exit 6
    echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
    daemon $nginx -c $NGINX_CONF_FILE
    retval=$?
    echo
    [ $retval -eq 0 ] && touch $lockfile
    return $retval
}

stop() {
    echo -n $"Stopping $prog: "
    killproc $prog -QUIT
    retval=$?
    echo
    [ $retval -eq 0 ] && rm -f $lockfile
    return $retval
}

restart() {
    configtest || return $?
    stop
    sleep 1
    start
}

reload() {
    configtest || return $?
    echo -n $"Reloading $prog: "
    killproc $nginx -HUP
    RETVAL=$?
    echo
}

force_reload() {
    restart
}

configtest() {
  $nginx -t -c $NGINX_CONF_FILE
}

rh_status() {
    status $prog
}

rh_status_q() {
    rh_status >/dev/null 2>&1
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        rh_status_q && exit 0
        $1
        ;;
    stop)
        rh_status_q || exit 0
        $1
        ;;
    restart|configtest)
        $1
        ;;
    reload)
        rh_status_q || exit 7
        $1
        ;;
    force-reload)
        force_reload
        ;;
    status)
        rh_status
        ;;
    condrestart|try-restart)
        rh_status_q || exit 0
            ;;
    *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart|condrestart|try-restart|reload|force-reload|configtest}"
        exit 2
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

Ans 1: You will not find lock file as it is being created in the script on starting the server. (check the line: `[ $retval -eq 0 ] && touch $lockfile`). The pid and lock file exits only when the application are running. When nginx is running, one may find the lock file here: /usr/local/nginx/logs/nginx.lock

Ans 2: Since your conf file is in default location(`/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`), I'm assuming that nginx will also be in default location ie `/usr/local/nginx/sbin`. This needs to be checked. 
I'm using RHEL 6.6 and also have installed nginx from source code. This is my init script as referred [here](https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/nginx-init-script/)

```
#!/bin/sh
# nginx - this script starts and stops the nginx daemon
#
# chkconfig:   - 85 15
# description:  NGINX is an HTTP(S) server, HTTP(S) reverse \
#               proxy and IMAP/POP3 proxy server
# processname: nginx
# config:      /usr/local/nginx/nginx.conf
# config:      /etc/sysconfig/nginx
# pidfile:     /var/run/nginx.pid /usr/local/nginx/logs
# Source function library.
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

# Source networking configuration.
. /etc/sysconfig/network

# Check that networking is up.
[ "$NETWORKING" = "no" ] && exit 0

nginx="/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx"
prog=$(basename $nginx)

NGINX_CONF_FILE="/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf"

[ -f /etc/sysconfig/nginx ] && . /etc/sysconfig/nginx

lockfile=/usr/local/nginx/logs/nginx.lock

make_dirs() {
    #make required directories

   user=`$nginx -V 2>&1 | grep "configure arguments:" | sed 's/[^*]*--user=\([^ ]*\).*/\1/g' -`

   options=`$nginx -V 2>&1 | grep 'configure arguments:'`
   for opt in $options; do
       if [ `echo $opt | grep '.*-temp-path'` ]; then
           value=`echo $opt | cut -d "=" -f 2`
           if [ ! -d "$value" ]; then
               # echo "creating" $value
               mkdir -p $value && chown -R $user $value
           fi
       fi
   done
}  

start() {
    [ -x $nginx ] || exit 5
    [ -f $NGINX_CONF_FILE ] || exit 6
    make_dirs
    echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
    daemon $nginx -c $NGINX_CONF_FILE
    retval=$?
    echo
    [ $retval -eq 0 ] && touch $lockfile
    return $retval
}

stop() {
    echo -n $"Stopping $prog: "
    killproc $prog -QUIT
    retval=$?
    echo
    [ $retval -eq 0 ] && rm -f $lockfile
    return $retval
}

restart() {
    configtest || return $?
    stop
    sleep 1
    start
}

reload() {
    configtest || return $?
    echo -n $"Reloading $prog: "
    killproc $nginx -HUP
    RETVAL=$?
    echo
}

force_reload() {
    restart
}

configtest() {
  $nginx -t -c $NGINX_CONF_FILE
}

rh_status() {
    status $prog
}

rh_status_q() {
    rh_status >/dev/null 2>&1
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        rh_status_q && exit 0
        $1
        ;;
    stop)
        rh_status_q || exit 0
        $1
        ;;
    restart|configtest)
        $1
        ;;
    reload)
        rh_status_q || exit 7
        $1
        ;;
    force-reload)
        force_reload
        ;;
    status)
        rh_status
        ;;
    condrestart|try-restart)
        rh_status_q || exit 0
            ;;
    *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart|condrestart|try-restart|reload|force-reload|configtest}"
        exit 2
esac
```

Other than this one would need to provide permission to the file

```
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/nginx -v
```

Add the script to the default runlevels:

```
chkconfig nginx on
```

Final step, test this out by running:

```
/etc/init.d/nginx start
/etc/init.d/nginx stop
/etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

By exporting the path to nginx, one will be directly able to run nginx.

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/nginx/sbin
```

Comment: @sunshine please try out this method and let me know whether it works or not.